# Cannot invoke "com.marin.thrift.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenRepository.save(Object)" because "this.confirmationTokenRepository" is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

I'm building my own store website, and I'm doing good so far, but I've come accross this error when I try to invoke this method confirmationTokenRepository.save(Object). I get an error message: "Cannot invoke "com.marin.thrift.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenRepository.save(Object)" because "this.confirmationTokenRepository" is null". I'm trying to send a token which will be "linked" to a users email which he will have to click to enable his account. I can see the user inside the database, but can't get token:

ConfirmationTokenService.java

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConfirmationTokenService {

private ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;

public void saveConfirmationToken(ConfirmationToken token) {
    confirmationTokenRepository.save(token);
    }
}
```

ConfirmationTokenRepository.java

```
package com.marin.thrift.registration.token;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface ConfirmationTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<ConfirmationToken, Long> {

    Optional<ConfirmationToken> findByToken(String token);
}
```

ConfirmationToken.java

```
package com.marin.thrift.registration.token;

import com.marin.thrift.entity.User;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "token")
@Entity
public class ConfirmationToken {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "token", nullable = false)
private String token;

@Column(name = "createdAt", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

@Column(name = "expiredAt")
private LocalDateTime expiredAt;

@Column(name = "confirmedAt")
private LocalDateTime confirmedAt;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
private User user;

public ConfirmationToken(String token, LocalDateTime createdAt, LocalDateTime expiredAt, User user) {
    this.token = token;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.expiredAt = expiredAt;
    this.user = user;
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.marin.thrift.service;

import com.marin.thrift.dao.UserRepository;
import com.marin.thrift.entity.User;
import com.marin.thrift.registration.token.ConfirmationToken;
import com.marin.thrift.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND = "user with email %s not found";
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
         return userRepository.findByUsername(email).orElseThrow(() -> new 
 UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND, email)));
     }

    public String singUpUser(User user) {
        boolean userExists = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getEmail()).isPresent();

        if (userExists) {
            return "user already in place";
        }

    String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);

    userRepository.save(user);

    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(token, LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15), user);

    confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

    return token;
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.marin.thrift.security.config;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final UserService userService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
            .disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

    provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);

    return provider;
}
```

Comment: You should add a @Autowired annotation above private ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;
Shouldn't you?

Comment: Make the field `final`, remove the `@NoArgsConstructor`.